# Adding ID of startpoint and endpoint to polyline layer using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro

I am copying from [Add ID of startpoint and endpoint to polyline layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213642) except that I am using ArcGIS Pro.

I have two layers: A point layer and a polyline layer. Each line starts and ends at a point from the point layer. For example: Line ID 5 from the polyline layer starts at point ID 7 from the point layer and ends at point ID 9.

Now I want to add two columns to the polyine layer and fill those with the IDs of the start point and end point. It doesn't matter which point is the start and which point is the end. I just want both IDs in two different fields.

I've tried intersect but that only adds the attributes of one of the points.

Is there a simple solution for this?